# how to boot widndows 8 uefi fromngrub command line?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have an emergency,I wanted to remove ubuntu from my pc, and I deleted the partitions of ubuntu, but now after a reboot, I'm stock in the grub command line

I need to enter to my windows 8 partition, I have already try love usb (not even boot) live CD, but nothing happens. please help.

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to boot Windows using the EFI boot menu (some function key at power-up, varies by machine).  Select "Windows" instead of "ubuntu".  That will skip grub completely, and just run Windows.  You should be able to re-arrange the boot order to put Windows first, so it becomes the default.
  If you really want to get to Windows through grub, you can use the grub commands:

```
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root <Your EFI UUID here>
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Comment: I have tried to use a Function key, but none seems to work, and with the command, it says that 7A11-7B8BB is not a device (such not device)

Comment: Change the 7A11-7B8B to the UUID of your EFI partition.  If you don't have a delay set for boot time, you have a harder time getting the function key to work, timing is everything, sometimes holding it down works.

Comment: @ubfan1 Please read http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting